# In linq to entity, how to retrieve objects matching a list of conditions without looping?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, join

I play with a mysql database using ADO entity framework (through devart dot.connect).

I get lists of entity objects (a) from listboxs and I would like to make a linq query retrieving all object from a given entity table (b) where there is a b foreign key:

```
//THIS WORKS :
IQueryable<Nb_student> nbstud = MainForm.context.Nb_student_set;
IQueryable<Cat_student> catstud = MainForm.context.Cat_student_set.Where(c => c.id == 2);

var test1 = from nb in nbstud
            join bb in catstud on nb.cat_student_id equals bb.id
            select nb;
```

=> this gives me only matching nb_students (this is what I want...)

Now, suppose instead of catstud, I have a list populated through a listbox.

```
IEnumerable<Cat_student> catstud2 = param_cat_students.AsEnumerable();
var ttt2 = from nb in nbstud
           join bb in catstud2 on nb.cat_student_id equals bb.id
           select nb;
```

=> it does't work, the error is the following: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."}
it seems there is a problem with the ids (int32) for the join ???

More generally, my question is : In Linq to Entity, how to select items from a table matching various lists of criterias (lists are not knowed in advance since they are choosen by the users) without making lot of loops. I thougth Join was the solution, I also tried the .any and .contains syntaxes without success :

```
var tt3 = from nb in nbstud.Where
          (nbx => catstud2.Any(cat => cat.id == nbx.cat_student_id)
          select nb;
```

If you could advice me... This is I suppose a very common problem but I don't know how to proceed.
Thanking you in advance,

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Linq 2 Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738638(VS.100).aspx) 4 I think you can do

```
/* Get ids of selected elements */
IEnumerable<int> catstud2 = param_cat_students.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.id);

/* Select the elements with the given ids from the database */
var ttt2 = from nb in nbstud where catstud2.Contains(nb.id);
```

If I remember correctly the `.Contains` will be translated to a SQL IN statement. However, I think there is an upper bound on the number of elements allowed in catstud2. You can also do this with Linq2SQL, while `.Contains` [is not supported in Linq2Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738638.aspx) 1.0.

If you are using Linq2Entities 1.0 I think you will have to make a choice between looping (and doing multiple single-element-lookups) and retrieving all of the contents of the table from the database into memory (using `.AsEnumerable()`), doing the join in memory.